# Lambda trigger doesn't replicate to SQS source across accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, policy

I'm trying to add an SQS as a source/trigger to a lambda.  I can do this just fine if both components reside within the same account.  When I add the trigger to the lambda, the lambda trigger configuration replicates over to the SQS queue to pair the two.

When I try this same thing on my lambda when the SQS is remote in a different account the Lambda trigger is established, but when viewing the remote SQS it doesn't show a trigger configured.  This seems to result in the trigger not working on the lambda when a message is added to the queue.  The SQS policy on the remote queue is also giving permissions explicitly to the other account as well.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Scenario:

- Amazon SQS queue in Account-A
- AWS Lambda function in Account-B
- Goal: SQS triggers Lambda function

Since this involves cross-account access, you will need to grant permissions for the IAM Role used by the Lambda function to access the SQS queue. (Lambda *pulls* from the queue, rather than SQS *pushing* to Lambda.)

The steps are:

- In the SQS queue, edit the **Access Policy** to include permission for the IAM Role used by the Lambda function:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-1:root"
      },
      "Action": "SQS:*",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:ACCOUNT-1:queue-name"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT-2:role/lambda-role-name"
      },
      "Action": [
        "SQS:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "SQS:DeleteMessage",
        "SQS:ReceiveMessage",
        "SQS:GetQueueAttributes"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:ap-southeast-2:ACCOUNT-1:queue-name"
    }
  ]
}
```

The first part of this policy is automatically created by SQS and allows the owning account to use the queue. The second part allows the IAM Role from Account-2 to access the queue in Account-1. The policy was created automatically by SQS when I created the queue and provided the ARN of the IAM Role. However, I had to add `SQS:GetQueueAttributes` because the Lambda function calls it too.

- In the AWS Lambda function in Account-B, click **+ Trigger**, select **SQS** and enter the ARN of the SQS queue from Account-A

I tried all this and was successfully able to put a message in SQS in Account-B, and then saw Lambda process it in Account-B.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried to recreate the same configuration, but got the following error when adding a trigger to my Lambda: `An error occurred when creating the trigger: The provided execution role does not have permissions to call ReceiveMessage on SQS (Service: AWSLambda; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValueException; Request ID: 880e49c6-8436-405a-a503-0d8a49d2b249; Proxy: null)`

Comment: @DmitriyPopov The message seems to be saying that the IAM Role associated with the AWS Lambda function needs to be given `sqs:ReceiveMessage` permission, either for all queues or at least for the SQS queue that it is trying to connect with. I notice that my descriptions above didn't mention what permissions I gave the Lambda role, so apologies about that.